# How to prevent calling jquery document.ready when using history.back(1)?

Tags: document-ready

Whenever I click the back button calling "history.back(1);"
the $(document).ready(...); is always triggered..

how to prevent it? I jsut want page loaded without doc.ready when back button clicked..

Comment: Ever find a solution? In my case, this is happening on Chrome and IE 8 but not Firefox.